# Obtaining the value of another process' CLR Memory Performance Counter

Tags: c#, performance, performancecounter

I have some C# code which starts up another process. Now I want to be able to obtain the value of the CLR Memory Performance counter for that process' Gen2 Heap size.

Can anybody get me started or direct me to a library which makes this easy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the PerformanceCounter class.  Like this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var process = "devenv";   // Modify this
        var ctr = new PerformanceCounter(".NET CLR Memory", "Gen 2 heap size", process);
        Console.WriteLine(ctr.RawValue);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to build is a code profiler, start reading here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5ec0es1.aspx.